# file name cannot be empty error while upload image

Tags: php

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty Warning:
>   getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty

error show like this and this is  my code

```
else {
  $image = addslashes(file_get_contents ($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name']));
  $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
  $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add if after else statmanet

```
if($_FILES['image']['name']>"")
```

Try this

```
else if($_FILES['image']['name']>""){
   $image = addslashes(file_get_contents ($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name']));
   $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
   $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
 }
```